# Prawn PDF Compression, compress content streams, what does it do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

The prawn gem has an initialize option `:compress`, which is described [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn%2FDocument%3Ainitialize).

Apparently it `"Compresses content streams before rendering them"`.

With and without `compress: true` I generated the same 14 page pdf twice. Each page has 2 photos and all sorts of text. The resulting file size was the exact same.

So my question is: in production with larger quantities of photos will I see a difference in file sizes? Or maybe `compress: true` eats more or less RAM during processing? What is its purpose?

Comment: Have you monitored memory usage? This might be useful on very large documents where trading CPU usage for a lighter memory footprint is worth it.

Comment: You may have better luck asking directly on their Google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/prawn-ruby

Comment: @Tass thanks that google group had the answers posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/prawn-ruby/compression|sort:relevance/prawn-ruby/_JK372mdEPs/lZAkgVDDJLEJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/prawn-ruby/compression|sort:relevance/prawn-ruby/RoEHWLgQNtI/IZLnm4Cfh_sJ), I now run both `compress: true` and `optimize_objects: true` per those answers and have seen no increase in CPU usage in production

Comment: That's great news, @BigRon! When I look for information about a gem I first go to their github repository. You'll usually find good documentation there, along with places to find answers for more complex scenarios. (A wiki, sometimes a google group.) And, in this case, mention of a google group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the full answers to the three questions

**1. In production with larger quantities of photos will I see a difference in file sizes?**

- not really. [Prawn doesn't downsample or scale 
  any images provided; we embed the image data as-is](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/prawn-ruby/compression|sort:relevance/prawn-ruby/RoEHWLgQNtI/IZLnm4Cfh_sJ)

**2. Or maybe `compress: true` eats more or less RAM during processing?**

- Anecdotally, for small-ish (<10MB) file sizes the extra RAM consumption associated with `compress: true` is negligible or non-existent. For larger file sizes your results may vary.

**3. What is its (`:compress`) purpose?**

- `:compress` compresses pdf content streams per the [prawn docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sandal/prawn/Prawn%2FDocument%3Ainitialize)
- pdf content streams are the binary data of the pdf objects. Multiple pdf objects can be combined into one content stream. Each content stream has an uncompressed text header which tells [the PDF parser how to find and extract the PDF objects, but all the PDF objects themselves can be compressed. This makes the PDF smaller, potentially more secure and possibly faster to load.](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/09/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-pdf-object-streams/)

Answer (score 2):

A more effective way to compress PDFs is to postprocess using Ghostscript, using a command such as:

```
ghostscript -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dUseCIEColor -dPDFSETTINGS=/printer -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=<output.pdf> <input.pdf>
```

This typically reduces the size of my Prawn-generated PDFs by 50% or more. The `dPDFSETTINGS` option can be set to different values to change the amount of compression - see the Ghostscript docs.

Comment: Can you tell me how can we use ghostscripts in ruby? I saw couple of gems like gs-ruby and rghost but none of them have a full detailed example of how can we make the script above work in ruby. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sorry, I just shell out to the command line (by enclosing the statement in backticks) rather than using a gem.

Comment: If anyone is still looking for this, I've managed to call it from ruby script.
    out, err, status = Open3.capture3("ps2pdf14 -", :stdin_data=>pdf.output, :binmode=>true)
The result is <10% pdf sizes, so really worth the effort.