# How to compress a pdf uploaded by a user in rails using Prawn Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I am new in rails and also in programming. I am trying to compress pdf using Prawn gem but I am not sure if it's the right gem to use or is there is another tool. A user is able to upload a pdf, but before save, I want to compress. I am using Active Storage for now and trying the following and is not working

```
elsif @test.tipo == 'pdf'
      pdf = params[:test][:book]
      mini_pdf = Prawn::Document.new(pdf.tempfile, :compress => true)
```

All I've done is install the gem. Nothing else.

Comment: If it works well, it seems like a good solution to me. If it could ever fail, you may want to rescue and return the original uncompressed PDF. Other tools can compress, but many are either commercial paid tools, or have an overly restrictive or expensive AGPL license if you are doing this for a commercial entity.

Comment: I don't think Prawn supports loading pdfs, just creating them. I would suggest trying [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) for that, though I'm not sure if it is able to compress the pdf..

Comment: You might want to look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444976/365218. Also, the question itself describes what `compress: true` actually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prawn is just a library for creating PDFs, not for manipulating them.

If you want to compress PDFs, have a look at [HexaPDF](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org) which is a fully-featured PDF library that can compress PDF files (see [an example](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/examples/optimizing.html) and [the compression benchmarks](https://hexapdf.gettalong.org/documentation/benchmarks/optimization.html)).

Nota bene: I'm the author of HexaPDF and HexaPDF is AGPL licensed with a commercial license available. It is currently probably the best pure-Ruby solution for handling PDFs.